# Global variables objects React-Native

Tags: variables, object, react-native, global

I have one class ContentManager on android objects and global variables ContentManager style, the aim is to create this object from one time only, you can get set properties for it anywhere in the app, now declared on React native the declaration is this? the picture below is me java code on android. Help!!!!!!!

[code in java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FT6Sy.png)

[code in java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9FO4a.png)

Answer (score 0):

create `global.js`

```
module.exports = {
  // your global variable
  },
};
```

Then require it at the top in your file

```
GLOBAL = require('../global');
```

for access

```
GLOBAL.your_variable_name
```